# Jquery Calculation - Decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, calculation

I've built a form, it works out a total, then another total, takes 4% away from the total and then gives the final value.

My issue is that i do not receive the decimal places to the calculation, so for example if the total price is £500 and the 4% removal is $52.10 my total value is 53, not 52.10.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znc93w90/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var insOn = 15;
  var insOff = 0;
  var insuranceCover = 0;
  var qtyy=jQuery("#wpforms-2562-field_5");
  var completetotal=jQuery("#totaltwo"); 

  qtyy.keyup(function(){
    //NewValue = 4% of the total
    var newValue = parseInt(completetotal.val()) * 0.04;  
    //FinalValue = Total - 4% - 25
    var finalValue = parseInt(completetotal.val()) - parseInt(newValue) - 25;  


    //Spit the totals out
    jQuery('#totalfinal').text(finalValue.toFixed(2));
    jQuery('#testing').text(newValue.toFixed(2));
    jQuery('#testingtwo').val(finalValue.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

Comment: `parseInt()` has the letters `I n t` in it for a reason.

Comment: @Pointy Care to point me in the right direction rather than stating the obvious?

Comment: If you need decimals then use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I've tried this, please could you show me in the jsfiddle?

Comment: You're using a function called `parseInt()` which returns an **integer**. There's no reason to pass a number (`newValue`) through any sort of number parsing function because it's *already a number*.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't parse your numbers to an Int:

```
    //NewValue = 4% of the total
    var newValue = completetotal.val() * 0.04;  
    //FinalValue = Total - 4% - 25
    var finalValue = completetotal.val() - newValue - 25;
```